# Le fait qu'un complément indirect se rattache au support ou au constituant d'une proposition infinitive change-t-il la qualité de la subordonnée ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, syntaxe, linguistique, compléments

> 1. La personne à laquelle/à qui (l')on a permis de partir plus tôt avait
>      de belles bottes.
>     *Permettre à quelqu'un de partir plus tôt.*
>      *Permettre de partir à quelqu'un plus tôt.*  (X)
>     *Permettre de
>      partir plus tôt à quelqu'un.* (X?)
> 2. La personne à laquelle/qui (l')on proposait de chanter s'est désistée.
>      
>     *Proposer à quelqu'un de chanter.*
>     *Proposer de chanter à
>      quelqu'un.* (X?)
> 3. La personne à laquelle/à qui (l')on voulait donner de l'argent s'est
>      révélée indigne.
>     *Vouloir donner de l'argent à quelqu'un.*
>      *Vouloir donner à quelqu'un de l'argent.* (X?)

En d'autres termes dans les deux premières phrases le complément indirect se rattacherait au verbe support (conjugué) alors que dans la troisième il se rattache au constituant infinitif. Est-ce que ça a un quelconque impact sur la qualité de la subordonnée ou sur une autre de ses caractéristiques :

- Peut-on valider l'adéquation des positions du complément indirect dans les pseudo-phrases (en italiques) ; est-ce que cette analyse ou le « nombre
  d'échecs » le cas échéant et/ou ultimement le complément adverbial (*plus tôt*) affectent la qualité de la subordonnée ou une autre de ses
  caractéristiques ?
- Les trois phrases sont-elles aussi claires ?
- Incidemment le *l'* est-il de l'hypercorrection ou simplement euphonique ?

Comment: Pourquoi je pose cette question bizarre ? Bien c'est que dans le cas de la première phrase, avec le pronom laquelle, il m'a fallu la relire 100 fois pour la trouver acceptable. Je ne sais pas si c'est simplement que je suis plus familier avec le pronom qui qu'avec laquelle, d'où l'autre question. Ensuite, j'ai lu un [truc](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00208086/document) que j'ai énormément de difficulté à comprendre pcq. je n'ai pas l'expertise alors j'ai construit un test pour tenter de déterminer quelque chose qui me permettrait de commencer à comprendre qqc. d'autre, d'où cette Q.

Comment: Ensuite je comprends mal la différence entre un pronom qui a la fonction de complément indirect et un pronom qui se substitue à un groupe prépositionnel et je ne sais pas s'il s'agit simplement d'une différence nature/fonction. Ensuite je comprends mal la différence entre la valence des verbes et leur transitivité. Et finalement je me demande si un type de complément rattaché au complément indirect peut nuire à l’enchâssement de propositions. Il y a un grand nombre de choses que je ne comprends pas et toutes les mentionner est beaucoup trop long.

Comment: Je ne sais pas pourquoi, mais le *à laquelle* me fait mal aux oreilles. Pas le *à qui* bien sûr.

Comment: @Damien : Pourquoi ? Mais c'est très simple : L'habitude sans doute.

Answer (score 2):

> dans les deux premières phrases

On va commencer par les analyser :

- *aCOSwt, à qui tu permettras de répondre, arrive.*

Proposition Principale : [aCOSwt arrive] *coupée* par

Proposition Relative : [tu permettras de répondre] *introduite* par [à qui]

Cette dernière est en fait constituée de **deux propositions** :

La relative proprement dite : [tu permettras]... *complétée* par une...

**Proposition complétive infinitive [de répondre]**

Proposition infinitive que l'on aurait tout aussi bien pu remplacer par une nouvelle proposition relative : *qu'il réponde*

Eh oui! C'est *toi* qui permets et *aCOSwt* qui répond, deux verbes aux sujets différents => deux propositions.

> le complément indirect se rattacherait au verbe support (conjugué)

On peut peut-être le dire ainsi. Mais de fait, tout est normal, l'objet indirect (de la relative) se comporte comme tout bon **OI** qui se respecte, se rattachant au verbe (de la relative) c'est encore bien à dire, ici, (cf supra) ***permettras***. Tu permets à aCOSwt!

(Exit l'infinitif qui ne fait pas partie de la même proposition. Et encore heureux tant : *Tu [permettras-de-répondre] à aCOSwt* changerait totalement le sens de la phrase.

> dans la troisième il se rattache au constituant infinitif.

- *Cette réponse, à laquelle tu daigneras accorder toute ton attention, est la meilleure.*

En ne s'attachant qu'à la proposition relative -*tu daigneras accorder toute ton attention*- on réalise qu'à la différence des deux autres, elle n'est constituée que d'**une seule proposition**.

C'est toi qui daignes et c'est aussi toi qui accordes. Le sujet des deux est identique. On ne pourrait écrire *tu daigneras que tu accordes*. L'infinitif n'est qu'un banal *complément infinitif* dans le groupe verbal *daigneras-accorder* de la seule proposition relative.

Identiquement, le COI comme tous les autres... se rapporte au groupe verbal. Ici [daigneras-accorder] (et non *daigneras* pris isolément)

> Est-ce que ça a un quelconque impact sur la qualité de la subordonnée
>   ou sur une autre de ses caractéristiques

De ce qui précède, je crains qu'il y ait dans cette question une inversion de cause à effet.

On l'a vu plus haut, dans tous les cas envisagés, le COI se comporte identiquement et se rattache partout et de la même manière au verbe de la relative. Il n'a donc aucune incidence sur cette dernière.

En revanche, comme on a pu le voir, **c'est la construction, la structure de la proposition subordonnée voire de l'enchaînement des subordonnées** qui, en ce qu'elles (comme en chaque occurrence) assignent à un et un seul process, un et un seul groupe verbal par proposition, **vont assigner le COI à un process particulier.**

L'impact est peut-être même plus important pour le COD, fonction qui, dans les deux premiers cas est assurée par une proposition. Le verbe est inclus dans le COD. Alors qu'il n'est qu'un banal syntagme nominal dans le troisième.

> Peut-on valider l'adéquation des positions du complément indirect dans
>   les pseudo-phrases

Oui absolument.

On dit l'ordre Sujet, verbe, objet-direct, objet-indirect *canonique*, car il est, dans un processus transitif, reconnu quasi fondamental-logique (/organisation de la pensée) de conserver le sujet et l'objet direct au plus proche du verbe.

Mais même ainsi, on peut observer dans la langue de nombreux cas où l'ordre OD,OI est inversé, l'OI se retrouvant alors lui, au plus proche du verbe.
Ainsi lorsque le syntagme COD sera significativement plus fourni (plus de mots, plus dense, plus développé) que le COI que le locuteur préférera évacuer tout de suite.

Ainsi, je dirai volontiers :

*Tu daigneras accorder toute ton attention à cette réponse* [V-COD-COI] Mais :

*Tu daigneras accorder à cette réponse toute cette méticuleuse attention dont tu es coutumier* [V-COI-COD]

Ainsi, **et pour cette seule raison**, je dirais effectivement **plus volontiers** :

- permettre à quelqu'un de partir plus tôt [V-COI-COD] que le très canonique (et donc très correct aussi :
- permettre de partir plus tôt à quelqu'un [V-COD-COI]

> est-ce que cette analyse ou le « nombre d'échecs » le cas échéant
>   et/ou ultimement le complément adverbial (plus tôt) affectent la
>   qualité de la subordonnée.

Non donc! L'importance du nombre d'échecs n'aura aucune influence. Seul le complément adverbial peut avoir un impact (**de pur style**) (et au même titre que tout autre complément ou complétive) **uniquement en tant que ce qu'il allonge le COD** par rapport au COI qu'on évacuera tout de suite histoire de... ne pas l'oublier à la fin. :-)

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : J'avoue avoir eu un peu de mal à comprendre la question posée. Il est donc possible que ma réponse soit à côté de la plaque.

Les conditionnels utilisés dans l'OP ont également joué sur l'orientation de la réponse. Il peut se trouver que j'enfonce en fait une porte déjà bien ouverte chez l'OP.

L'un des deux cas échéant, merci à l'OP de commenter dans ce sens, je verrai comment modifier ma réponse.</sup>

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Les deux dernières questions sont affaires de style de goût et d'habitude => Chacun son truc!</sup>

<sup>NDaCOSwt : Le second commentaire de l'OP évoque deux autres problèmes (le remplacement par des pronoms et la valence des verbes) qui, à mon opinion, pour être aussi valables qu'importants, ne me semblent reliés à cette question que de façon connexe.</sup>

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous : Merci pour ta relecture attentive. Effectivement, il y avait un pb d'accord et de typo. Corrigé.